# Is there an elegant way to move all sub-directories in the current directory to a new sub-directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix

I often run into the following situation. I am in a directory with several sub-directories like so

```
$ls 
a b c d
```

I would like to archive directories `a-d` by moving them into a new directory at the same level called `archive`.  Ie:

```
$ls 
archive

$ls archive
a b c d
```

The way I currently do this is to make `archive` and then do a move all.  I don't like this though because you always get the error `mv: cannot move 'archive' to a subdirectory of itself, 'archive/archive'.  While this works I don't like the fact I am 'abusing' the built-in exception handling.

```
$mkdir archive

$mv * archive/
`mv: cannot move 'archive' to a subdirectory of itself, 'archive/archive'
```

Ideally I would like a solution that does not involve errors. Something along the lines of mv automatically creating the directory but unfortunately that does not work.

```
$mv * archive/
mv: target 'archive/' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Bash-specific approach is to use `GLOBIGNORE`:

```
GLOBIGNORE=archive
```

(or maybe `GLOBIGNORE=archive:.*`, see the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)).

Then the expansion of `*` in `mv * archive/` (or wherever) will not contain `archive`. `unset GLOBIGNORE` afterwards or plan ahead and run the commands in a subshell:

```
(GLOBIGNORE=archive; mv * archive/)
```

Note `GLOBIGNORE=archive mv * archive/` will not work because you need the variable in a shell that expands `*`, not in the environment of `mv`.

Comment: Thanks!  I chose this answer because it is concise and doesn't require cleanup (running in a subshell is a nice idea)

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of expansion of `*` before you create `archive`. Something like:

```sh
set -- *
mkdir archive
mv -- "$@" archive/
```

<sup>([`--` explained](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618))</sup>

The above solution is portable.

Run the code in a separate (sub)shell to preserve original positional parameters. Or in Bash (but not in plain `sh`) use an array:

```bsh
foo=(*)
mkdir archive
mv -- "${foo[@]}" archive/
unset foo
```

But then you need to pick an *unused* name (here: `foo`), otherwise you will lose the original content of the variable. Therefore using a subshell is still a good idea. If in a subshell then there is no point of not using the portable approach. The resulting code may be:

```sh
(
set -- *
mkdir archive
mv -- "$@" archive/
)
```

Note `mkdir` may fail. Usually it's not a problem when you work (type commands) interactively. But with `( )` the snippet will run only after you send the closing `)`. For this reason you may want to abort if `mkdir` fails (e.g. `mkdir archive || exit 1`). Alternatively work in an interactive child shell:

```sh
# interactively
bash              # starting a child shell
# now interactively in a new shell
set -- *
# do whatever you need to do
exit              # exiting the child shell
# now back in the original shell
```

In practice I would probably forget to `exit`. This error may or may not cause confusion later.

Frankly, how often do you need the original positional parameters in an *interactive* shell? You probably don't need them, so the very first snippet without a subshell ([simple and straightforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The find command with one level depth scan for sub-directories would also perform the move to archive directory:

```
# Create archive dir if not present
mkdir -p archive

# Test first with echo command:
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ! -name archive -exec echo mv {} archive \;

# Run it:
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d ! -name archive -exec mv {} archive \;
```

Remove `-type d` if wanting to move files too.